What is this insect in this image?

Is it an insect coming out of its cocoon or some other type ?
It was attached on wall like a leech and was not able to detach from that because it was glued.
Location :- northern India

It's very hard to see details on your picture. Do you have something higher resolution or possibly good pictures of different parts?
